# Where to put dom manipulation of small scripts in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, dom

I'm new to angular and i'm wondering where to put some code. I know that dom manipulation should not happen in a controller but in a directive.

Do i realy have to create a directive for this small bit of javascript code (a click on a button adds a class to the `<body>` tag?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a directive. Multiplying directives in your code base is not a bad thing at all. Look at the angular source code for directives like ngBind, and you'll realise that small doesn't matter at all, it is quite the opposite (directives are meant to be specialised).